# Is it possible to set or modify "origin" header in an https request?

Tags: html, security, cross-domain, hmacsha1

I am building a web page that will be embedded on a third party website using iframe. No login service is required to initiate the communication so I can't manage any session token.

Therefore, I am planning to validate the `origin` header of the https request to check if the request comes from the expected source. This external website is not in my control but I can ask them to make some changes to achieve secure communication.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to set or modify "origin" header maliciously in an https request? Or is it always set by browser itself?
2. Because I am not very sure of the level of security provided by `origin` header I plan to use HMAC-SHA256 as well. The external site should generate a unique number for each request and sign it with secret key.

So, if I implement the above two things, is there anything else I should be worried about?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is set/guaranteed by the browser. An attacker does not have to use a browser - an Origin header is *no more suitable* for this than a Referer header, which is "use at your own risk". (I'm not exactly sure what the approach with the hash is supposed to solve.. but if the client generates it, it is *not* a secured resource.)

Comment: @user2864740: Yes, agree on the 'origin' header. It is not really useful. With the HMAC I will service the request for which the request signature matches with the signature generated on server side. Since, an attacker doesn't know the secret key required to generate a valid HMAC signature I am well protected. Of course an attacker can still send a request but it won't be serviced because of mismatch in signature.

Comment: Might as well just send the access key / nonce as plain text, no?

Comment: Yes, fair point. A lot of article suggest that but I don't see any value add in sending access id. Nonce as per my understanding is used to prevent replay or retransmit of a message. In my case a unique number is mandatory in request and it is a part of signature as well. So I think this unique number is acting as a 'nonce' for me.

Comment: As long as it can't be guessed and has a controlled (eg. one-use or time-limited) lifetime.